# Matching GPS coordinates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gps, match, lookup

I am looking for a tool to match GPS coordinates. Attached is a sheet with a list of GPS coordinates.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pCVlq7BEUBQyST0iRoPcgp_XUhUyOYjAuPQ3mfR5ehU/edit#gid=0

I tried array but I cannot make 1 cell subtract from a column and even if I do it is taking a very long method.

Do you have any suggestion of what I can use?
I ideal situation I’m hoping for is that it checks the list of coordinates and highlight the coordinates that exist more than once, say within 300meters.

I use this formula to calculate distance between 2 points
= 111*SQRT((X1-X2)^2+(Y1-Y2)^2)
Each change in degree of GPS coordinate, corresponds to 111km on geographical scale approx.

Comment: Have you tried using a script in your spreadhseet? Would you consider using a script to achieve your purpose?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of scripts, but yes! If you can suggest some basic ideas for scripts..that would really helpful

Comment: Perfect, just a one last questions before of posting an answer. Do you want to calculate the distance between all the coordinates in your list to see any pair matches (i.e check from R1 to R346 to see if there is any pair of them within 300 meters) or do you want to set a coordinate and see if it is close to any of the coordinates of your list ? Thanks !

Comment: the first one...see any pair matches. I was able to do the second one...but that is a manual method and will take me a long time when I have 2000 such coordinates..Thanks so much for looking into this...

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You can check the coordinate points that are closer than a specific distance by creating, in another sheet, a matrix of distances between all the points and by using conditional formatting to highlight the pair of points that are closer than a specific distance.

Steps to achieve this:

1. Create a new sheet in your Spreadsheet.
2. In the first cell insert the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SQRT(POW(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$B"&(COLUMN(B2)))-Sheet1!$B2:$B340,2) + POW(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$C"&(COLUMN(B2)))-Sheet1!$C2:$C340,2)))`

> Formula explanation : This formula calculates the euclidean distance between two coordinate points. I have used `ARRAY FORMULA` to automatically calculate the distance between the first point with the rest of the coordinates of your GPS signal. Note that indirect is used so that you can propagate this formula to the rest of the columns. In this case I am testing with 340 coordinate points but you can increase this as you want.

4. Select the cell where you wrote the formula in and drag it through the columns until you reach your total number of elements. (You can easily check this when the 0s diagonal reaches the last row of values).
5. Select your whole range (matrix) and head over to **Format -> Conditional Formatting** and then in the UI in **Less or equal than** choose the distance you wish to put as the limit.

In this way you will have this distance matrix telling you which intersection points are closer than a specific distance. This is an example image of how it would look like (for distances smaller than 0.4):

[image]

**Resources used :**

> [ARRAYFORUMLA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), [POW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093603?hl=en), [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en), [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: That works! Thank you so much, Mateo!! I'll try to use indexing or hlookup to find the matching coordinates. This really helps!!

Comment: Glad to hear that ! Pleease, consider accepting my answer or upvoting it so that other users with similar questions can easily see that it worked :D

Comment: i'm not an active user, so I do not have the required reputation...however, if someone upvotes my question I will ;-)

Comment: Someone has completed the spreadsheet example linked in Mannan's question.  It now uses Mateo's formula, illustrating his answer.   Really helpful.